# iOS Device Token & Push Notification Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

Can someone help on how to get device token on ios using ionic only. I've managed to get device token using Xcode but is it possible to get device token using ionic only?

I need to to add the device token when the users log in the app

Comment: Under the hood its plugin talking native to javascript. You can use plugin where you won't to have code in native.

Answer (score 4):

## Try this

using this plugin

```
   cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXX"
```

### after that adding this

in to ionicPlatform.ready

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": {
        "senderID": "SENDER-ID"
    },
    "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
    "windows": {} 
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    console.log("registration event");
    //here is your registration id
    console.log(data.registrationId);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be very late in answering your question, your answer is as below

1. Update your ionic to latest version i,e v2 and above.
2. Then create a project and add this plugin

> cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable
>   SENDER_ID="XXXXXXXXX

3. Next goto src/app/app.component.ts file and add this code after platform.ready().then(()

   ```
   var push = Push.init({
       android: {
         senderID: "XXXXXXXXX"
       },
       ios: {
         alert: "true",
         badge: true,
         sound: 'false'
       },
       windows: {}
     });
     push.on('registration', (data) => {
       console.log(data.registrationId);
       alert(data.registrationId.toString());              
     });
   ```

   push.on('notification', (data) => {
       console.log(data);
        alert("Hi, Am a push notification");
     });
4. Perform all the certification part according to apple guidelines(if
   any problem please do comment).
5. Finally implement push notification server side either in java or php or ionic.io ! All the best...